# Using CognitoSyncManager in Android Studio

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-cognito

I am developing an app in Android Studio and I would like to be able to access existing Cognito user datasets shared by an iOS version of the same app. In all of the examples I see for dealing with datasets, I see `CognitoSyncManager` used to manage datasets. However, I am unable to import this class with `import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager`, as this generates an error which says that I cannot import `cognito`. (I can import `com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider`, but this doesn't seem to contain CognitoSyncManager.) In case it makes a difference, I am basing my code off of [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) sample code. I've looked around but every example for Android I see tells me to use the import I mentioned. What is the correct way to access my datasets in Android Studio?

Comment: Cognito user pools and Cognito sync are two different services that require two different imports. Can you share what AWS services/SDKs you're importing?

Comment: I checked and it looks like I forgot to import the necessary Coginto SDK. Now everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I checked my app.gradle file for my imports after seeing Jeff Bailey's comment and noticed that I was missing the necessary Cognito import. After adding the line:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.+'
```

I was able to import CognitoSyncManager and everything seems to be working now.